# Contar registros agrupados los 3 mas altos y el resto en un solo grupo, Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Me encuentro realizando un reporte de datos de mysql por cantidad de agencias en una ciudad, ya he realizado el conteo, pero requiero mostrar los tres mas altos y las demas en un grupo llamado "otros", ejemplo:

(asi seria ya con los datos contados y agrupados)

```
select ciudad, count(id_agencia) cantidad 
from agencias 
group by ciudad 
order by cantidad desc;
```

Lo que da como resultado:

```
Ciudad          |Cantidad
-----------------------------
Calí            |22  
Medellín        |18   
Bogotá          |15  
Cartagena       |10  
Bucaramanga     |6  
Pasto           |4
```

Lo que busco es obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
Ciudad          |Cantidad
-----------------------------
Calí            |22  
Medellín        |18   
Bogotá          |15  
Otras ciudades  |20
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, y ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? Te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras, gracias. Ya he intentado usar un where con "not in" en una subconsulta, pero esperaba no tener que repetir el script, y los resultados fueron inesperados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizar esa consulta puede parecer complicado ya que se debe hacer uso de varias operaciones:

Primero hace falta obtener la consulta que muestre la cantidad de agencias por ciudad ordenadas:

```
select E.ciudad, count(id_agencia) as cantidad
from agencias E
GROUP BY E.ciudad
order by cantidad desc
```

luego para obtener solo las primeras 3 colocamos al final:

```
limit 3
```

con la misma consulta inicial podemos obtener las ciudades del 4 para adelante con:

```
limit 3, 100
```

con esta segunda podemos hacer una subconsulta para sumar el total de las otras ciudades con sum, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 'Otras ciudades',sum(cantidad)
from (select E.ciudad, count(*) as cantidad
from  agencias E
GROUP BY E.ciudad
order by cantidad desc
limit 3, 100)
```

Así solo queda unir la primera consulta con la segunda, para esto colocamos la primera dentro de una subconsulta y empleamos `union` quedando la consulta final así:

```
select T.ciudad, T.cantidad
from (select E.ciudad, count(id_agencia) as cantidad
from agencias E
GROUP BY E.ciudad
order by cantidad desc
limit 3) T1
union 
SELECT 'Otras ciudades',sum(cantidad)
from (select E.ciudad, count(id_agencia) as cantidad
from  agencias E
GROUP BY E.ciudad
order by cantidad desc
limit 3, 100) T2
```

y de ese modo la consulta mostrará:

```
Ciudad          |Cantidad
--------------------------
Calí            |22
Medellín        |18
Bogotá          |15
Otras ciudades  |20
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: habia intentado el union, pero no habia tenido en cuenta el limit, ha sido muy útil, supongo que en consultas mas complejas con joins tendre que hacer algo similar, éste es un buen punto de partida.